# Why doesn't a bus blow due to internal pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, solid-mechanics

When one travels in a bus, if he's sitting at any window, he will feel that the air is coming inside.  If someone is standing at the open door of the bus, he'll also feel that the air is coming inside. 
If so much air is coming inside, why doesn't the bus blow due to internal pressure?

Comment: Thanks for that mental image when I go home today by public transportation!

Answer (score 18):

The more interesting question is, "What does air feel like when it is moving away from me?" The answer is that there is really no sensation at all. You feel all the air coming into the vehicle, because it has a bulk momentum with respect to your frame of reference. However, air being sucked out of those same windows and doors is being pulled from a large volume in many directions - it doesn't give much of a sensation, and so you don't notice it.

Comment: I believe this is similar to the [Feynman sprinkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler) effect.