# Why does blowing on a candle put it out but sucking doesn't?

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment, air

Alternatively, why does the force created by blowing out air feel so much stronger than the force created by sucking in air?

Ok, so forget the human factor involved in *blowing out candles*. Consider a vacuum cleaner with a suction end and a blower end. Anyone who has tried it out notices the blower end creates a much stronger force than the suction end, despite the discharge being (more or less) equal at both ends.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Fundamentally, the same ideas underlie a related inquiry: [Why doesn't a bus blow due to internal pressure?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64647)

Comment: Also related: [What happens, if a rocket is filled with a vacuum instead of high pressured air?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74240/)

Comment: I read in a bio of Richard Feynman, about a fun question, that has a similar answer: what happens if you invert the flow in one of those rotating water sprayers? In what direction does it turn?

Comment: @ÉmileJetzer, the bio is titled "Surely you're joking, Mr. Feynman". The problem is called the _Feynman Sprinkler problem_. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler

Comment: Is it possible that blowing air from a vacuum hose is mostly turbulent airflow but sucking is much more a laminar airflow, therefore less "disturbing"?

Comment: Note that if you put your hand at the back of a fan (i.e. the "sucking" side), it feels much milder than putting it at the front (i.e. the "blowing" side). And what does subjecting a flame to only a mild breeze do?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In a blower, the air is directed along the axis of the blower as it exits, creating a high-pressure narrow cone. Exit pressure can also be multiple times of atmospheric pressure.

At a sucker entry, the low-pressure zone is fed by a much wider angle of atmospheric air at atmospheric pressure. Additionally, the underpressure can at most be 1x atmospheric pressure. therefore the inflow has an upper limit to its velocity.

Comment: The difference is easily felt if you hold your hand close to your mouth. You can barely feel the wind from the sucking.

Comment: However, why blowing create a directional narrow path, but sucking is fed by a wider angle?

Answer (score 22):

Watch water going down a drain. It has a rotational symmetry and goes into a [vortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex), whose boundary conditions perpendicular to the flow cover an area much larger than the hole of the drain.

Watch water coming out of a hose. The boundary conditions defining the vortex are to start with the area of the hose perpendicular to the motion.

It is the same with the air, blowing out the mouth is the bound of the vortex thus the energy per unit area carried by the flow is much larger than by inhaling. In inhaling the vortex boundaries are variable but certainly much larger than the hole of the mouth, thus the energy carried by the induced flow of air per unit area is much smaller.

It is the impact of air that blows out the candle, and the area of the flame is small so that a directional blow from the mouth can turn it off. In inhaling the area covered by the flow cannot be controlled and the energy per unit area impacting the flame is much smaller.

Comment: Fantastic!: I was groping for something like this but really had no idea how to condense my squabbling thoughts into an answer.