# Cooling - in vs out?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose I have a 20x20x20 c"m plastic box where the top cover is open.

On the top cover there is a fan ( 20x20 cm) which suppose to cool a cpu which is in the box .

At the bottom  there is a CPU which is getting warm.

Now - in order to cool the CPU - I have 2 options :

- put the fan to suck air from the box towards outside
- put the fan to push air from outside towards the box.

**Final goal :**

Max - Cooling the cpu.

**Question:**

Which is the preferred approach ?

Comment: Hint: Hold out your palm and blow onto it. Then suck from it. Which one creates more flow?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I could answer you in this way : when I push the air inside Im actually keeping the worm inside while When I suck the air - I'm getting the worm outside faster .......... **BUT** I could also the opposite. hence my question.

Comment: Try it in a box with one end open, see what happens.

Comment: are you serious I cant test it. that's why i ask it. tnx

Comment: Are you serious? This has a really simple answer, and I'm asking you to put your hand in any box which has one end open - not that difficult to improvise - and then blow and then suck air and see which one you think makes more sense to use. As for "keeping the warm in / getting the warm out", it's a better idea to have an inlet _and_ outlet for the airflow.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi FYI todays computers uses sucking air rather than pushing.... but from my testing it's the opposite which  is better. so im in a bit of a conflict here .never mind i'll wait for more scientific explanation. thank you.

Comment: Wait, what? Every computer I've used has pushed air onto the chip. The scientific explanation is that more airflow = more cooling. For the reason for _why_ more airflow, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75945/why-does-blowing-on-a-candle-put-it-out-but-sucking-doesnt

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes but  below the power supply there is a cooler which sucks heat out..... I dont believe it's doing it's job for nothing

Comment: @PranavHosangadi http://i.stack.imgur.com/QULNh.jpg.... **so im confused**